# Laravel 5.8 y DataTables Tablas relacionadas

Tags: php, javascript, sql, laravel, datatables

Hola buen día lo que pasa es que cuando tengo una relación en mis tablas al momento de mostrarlas en las tablas me aparece solo el id que le pertenece y me gustaría que saliera el nombre así como en una tabla normal por ejemplo:

```
<td>{{$cl->agencia->titulo_a}}</td>
```

este es el modelo del producto

```html
class Producto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'productos';

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'titulo'
    ];

    protected $primarykey = 'id';

    public function categoriaProducto(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CategoriaProducto');
    }

    public function precioProducto(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\PrecioProducto');
    }

}
```

este es el modelo del precioproducto

```html
class PrecioProducto extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'precioproducto';
    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id','precio'
    ];

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function producto(){
        return $this ->belongsTo('App\Producto');
    }
}
```

este es mi controlador

```html
class PrecioProductoController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $precioproducto = PrecioProducto::all();
        $producto = Producto::all();
        if(request()->ajax()){
            return datatables()->of(PrecioProducto::latest()->get())
                ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                    $button = '<button type="button" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'"
                class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editar</button>';
                    $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                    $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>';
                    return $button;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
        }
        return view('PrecioProducto.index', compact('precioproducto','producto'));
    }
```

y a qui esta mi script de datatable

```js
 ajax:{
                    url: "{{ route('PrecioProducto.index') }}",
                },
                columns:[
                    {
                        data: 'product_id',
                        name: 'product_id'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'precio',
                        name: 'precio'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'created_at',
                        name: 'created_at'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'updated_at',
                        name: 'updated_at'
                    },
                    {
                        data: 'action',
                        name: 'action',
                        orderable: false
                    }
                ]
            });
```

y el resultado es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde el la seccion producto me gustaria que saliera el titulo del producto no el id, me podrian ayudar ?

Comment: @Aprendiz así es estoy trabajando con Eloquent

Comment: @Aprendiz listo

Answer (score 3):

Ya lo resolví en mi controlador agregue una columna con la relación en las tablas

```js
->addColumn('title',function($producto){
                    return $producto->Producto->titulo;
                })
```

ese codigo se agrega antes de donde especifique los botones y en el js de datatable solo puse 
data: 'title';

y mostro el resultado como lo muestro ahora
[image: ya reconoce los productos asociados a los precios del producto en el que se tiene la relación, de igual forma funciono con mis otras tablas en mi sistema]

Comment: me salvaste con tu solucion!

Comment: Buena solucion amigo, lo unico malo es que el search no puede buscar en esas columnas :c

Answer (score 1):

En vez de

```
product_id
```

debería ser

```
producto.titulo
```

Comment: ya lo intente de esa manera y por eso hice la pregunta por no me da el resultado, al ponerle producto.titulo me arroja el mensaje, undefined index; producto.titulo

Comment: Estas cargando la relación producto cuando traes lo precios de la base de datos?

Comment: creo que no, como seria un ejemplo ?

Comment: Como cargas los modelos PrecioProducto en tu controlador?

Comment: utilizo:
use App\Producto;
use App\PrecioProducto

Comment: Pero como obtienes los records de la base datos. Algo así como: PrecioProduct::all() o PrecioProduct::get() ?

Comment: estan especificados en mi controlador que puse arriba 
 $precioproducto = PrecioProducto::all();
 $producto = Producto::all();
//ajax
return view('PrecioProducto.index', compact('precioproducto','producto'));

Comment: OK. En vez de  PrecioProducto::all(); debería ser algo como  PrecioProducto::with('producto')->get();

Comment: ya lo pobre de esa forma y enseguida puse en el script data: producto.titulo pero no aparece nada y si lo devueldo a product_id solo muestra el id del producto

Comment: Lo otro, podrías cambiar PrecioProducto::latest()->get() a PrecioProducto::with('producto')->latest()->get()

Comment: ya lo probe asi, esta un poco raro.
Voy a revisar la documentación de nuevo, algo se me esta escapando

Comment: Si. Igual está raro que cargues dos veces las filas de PrecioProducto.

Comment: y si pones solo `titulo` en el ajax?